# Count occurences of elements of a matrix fast

Tags: python, numpy

Let **M** and **n** be **d x d**- and **d**-dimensonal numpy arrays of integers, respectively. I want to count the number of triples of the form *(n(i), n(j), M(i,j))*. As a result I want a numpy array such that each entry counts the number of occurences of such a triple.

*Edit:* **M** is symmetric and I don't want to count triples with i=j.

I'm currently using `itertools.product` (for loop over all pairs) and `numpy.bincount` to do this, but it is too slow. Is there a smarter way doing this, probably using `numpy`?

Comment: Could list a sample input, output and also the code that you tried?

Comment: What is a typical value of `d`?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Thanks, corrected it. About 100.

Comment: Triplet `(n(i), n(j), M(i,j))` would be different than `(n(j), n(i), M(i,j))` if the order is important, right? So, that symmetric case might not really assist I think.

Comment: @Divakar: Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the arrays contain integers, you can consider each triplet as an linearly index-able element. Here's an approach with that *philosophy* in mind and thus avoids loops, like so -

```
# Form n(i) x n(j) array and then append with "columnar" M(i,j) array
nn_arr = n[np.array(list(itertools.product(range(5), repeat=2)))]

nn_M_arr = np.concatenate((nn_arr,M.reshape(-1,1)),axis=1)

# Get linear indices version
dims = nn_M_arr.max(0)+1
lidx = np.ravel_multi_index(nn_M_arr.T,dims)

# Get unique indices and the counts
_, idx, counts = np.unique(lidx,return_index=True,return_counts=True)

# Get corresponding unique triplets using unique indices and zip with counts
out = zip(map(tuple,nn_M_arr[idx]),counts)
```

Sample run -

```
In [206]: M
Out[206]: 
array([[1, 0, 0, 2, 0],
       [1, 1, 2, 0, 2],
       [0, 0, 2, 0, 1],
       [2, 1, 2, 0, 2],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 0]])

In [207]: n
Out[207]: array([0, 1, 1, 1, 2])

In [208]: out
Out[208]: 
[((0, 0, 1), 1),
 ((0, 1, 0), 2),
 ((0, 1, 2), 1),
 ((0, 2, 0), 1),
 ((1, 0, 0), 1),
 ((1, 0, 1), 1),
 ((1, 0, 2), 1),
 ((1, 1, 0), 4),
 ((1, 1, 1), 2),
 ((1, 1, 2), 3),
 ((1, 2, 1), 1),
 ((1, 2, 2), 2),
 ((2, 0, 1), 1),
 ((2, 1, 1), 3),
 ((2, 2, 0), 1)]
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it also possible to adapt your approach such that triples with i=j are not counted?

Comment: @Christopher Yes! Substitute `nn_M_arr` with `nn_M_arr[~np.eye(n.size,dtype=bool).ravel()]`.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Unfortunality, I'm using numpy 1.8.2 (I can't update for now). Hence, I don't have ``return_counts=True``. Is it possible to adapt your approach using, e.g., ``bincount``?

Comment: @Christopher Can  you use np.unique with `return_inverse` option? If so, you can do : `_, idx, inv_idx = np.unique(lidx,return_index=True,return_inverse=True)` and then `counts` would be simply `np.bincount(inv_idx)`.

Comment: @Davakar Is it also possible to exclude triples with a certain value of M(i,j), e.g. "inf"?

Comment: @Christopher I guess do `nn_M_arr = nn_M_arr[~np.isinf(M.ravel())]`.

Comment: Thanks! Is your approach also possible, when you have another d-dimensonal numpy array m and want to count (n(i), m(j), n(j), m(j), M(i,j))?

Comment: @Christopher Nope, would involve some good changes for that. Please consider posting another question on that.

Comment: Just that I understand correctly: 
``np.concatenate((nn_arr,M.reshape(-1,1)),axis=1)`` builds an array that contains all triples, right?

Answer (score 1):

Let :

```
M=np.random.randint(0,3,(10,10))
n=np.random.randint(0,3,10)
```

Making triples and drop i=j :

```
x,y=np.meshgrid(n,n)
a=np.dstack((x,y,M)).reshape(-1,3)
au=a[a [:,0]!=a[:,1]]   # i<>j
```

The problem with unique is that it use only 1D array. a solution  is to convert rows in strings : this ensure lazy comparisons and is generally fast.

```
c=np.frombuffer(au,dtype='S12')   # 12 is  3*n.itemsize

_,indices,counts=np.unique(c,return_index=True,return_counts=True)

result=np.vstack((counts,au[indices].T)) # count first.

##
array([[1, 2, 5, 3, 4, 1, 4, 4, 3, 4, 9, 1, 3, 4, 9, 3, 4],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]], dtype=int64)
```

If integers are small like here (<4), you can present the results so that `res[n(i),n(j),M(i,j)]`give the count :

```
res=np.zeros((3,3,3),int) 
res[list(zip(*au[indices]))]=counts
```

Comment: Your code seems to output a matrix, or did I miss something?

Comment: Perharps I don't understand : " I want a numpy array such that each entry counts the number of occurences of such a triple" . Can you precise your will by an example ?

Comment: It should be an one-dimensional array, such that each entry contains the number of occurences of a triple. E.g. if the triple (1,3,4) appears 3 times, there should be an entry with the number '3'.

Comment: Ok. so the result can just be the counts array. but how to know it is associate to the (1,3,4) entry ? with struct array you can have an array so that a['(1,3,4)']=3, after converting tuple in string. it is that ? or will you a[1,3,4]= 3 ? In this case max(m) must be integer and little . Edited for this case– B. M. 1 hour ago